# SMT solving with less-than theory and monotonic functions

Tags: sat, model-checking, formal-methods

I am attempting to solve a less-than theory within an SMT paradigm that involves variables assigned to reals and assumes that all the functions used in the theory are monotonic. The theory's signature has the terms denoted as T and the formulas are denoted as φ. The syntax is given as follows:

$$T = x \mid f(T) \tag{1}$$
$$φ = T < T \mid ¬φ \mid φ ∧ φ \mid φ ∨ φ \tag{2}$$

An example formula in this domain is:

$$(x < y) ∧ (y < z) ∧ ((f(z) < f(y)) ∨ (f(x) < f(z)))$$

How would I begin thinking about how to encode a general formula within the less-than theory as a SAT problem? What is the decision process and encoding algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 straight forward approaches

1. Directly add $\forall xy (x < y \Rightarrow f(x) < f(y))$.
2. Or Akcermannize the problem and add these as axioms for all pairs of terms.

Comment: So, if I split each variable and function into its own class, do classes that fulfill criteria 1 become merged? Similar to uninterpreted functions theory

Comment: I don't know what you mean by classes or merging. These are just additional axioms. In version 2 you just add them after you've Ackermannized everything